# Oracle sql missing right parenthesis

Tags: sql, oracle10g, left-join

I'm trying to limit the number of rows that would be displayed when I run my query.
When I run the code below in SQL developer, it returns missing right parenthesis error..

```
select * from
(select row_number()  over (order by rescode) rnum, a.* from
    (    
     SELECT * 
     FROM trans z 
     LEFT JOIN emails a 
     ON z.email1_hist_id=a.email_id 
     or z.email2_hist_id=a.email_id 
    ) a
)   where rnum between 1 and 50;
```

I tried running the inside query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM trans z 
LEFT JOIN emails a 
ON z.email1_hist_id=a.email_id 
or z.email2_hist_id=a.email_id
```

and it works fine. On the other hand I tried removing the OR portion of my query and included the limit rows query and it returns the number of rows I specified.

What exactly is wrong in my code?

Comment: I would try also the part that starts with `select row_number()` and ends with `) a`. Anyway, the error seems silly. It may probably be the particular arrangement of some elements of your query that causes the error. Personally I would try these (one by one or in combinations): putting `a.*` before `row_number()...`; leaving the `(` before `select row_number()...` on a separate line; leaving the `)` before `where rnum...` on a separate line; conversely, placing `SELECT *` of the most inner select on the same line with the preceding `(`; similarly merge the lines of `) a` and `) where rnum...`.

Answer (score 1):

This should work - you don't need two levels of subquery

```
select *
from
(    SELECT *, row_number()  over (order by rescode) rnum
     FROM trans z 
     LEFT JOIN emails a 
     ON (z.email1_hist_id=a.email_id or z.email2_hist_id=a.email_id)
) x
where rnum between 1 and 50;
```

Also, make sure there are no duplicate column names between `trans` and `emails` - this will trip the query because `*` from the inner query cannot return duplicate names.

Answer (score 0):

My best guess is that it doesn't like your giving the sub-selection an alias, so it's throwing the syntax error at the "a" in ") a )".

Answer (score 0):

I don't recall about Oracle, but I know that MySQL actually requires sub-selections to have an alias.  I'd try adding one to your outer sub-select (before the where rnum...).

Comment: I tried this:
select * from
(select row_number()  over (order by reservation_code) rnum, b.* from(  
  SELECT * FROM trans z 
  LEFT JOIN emails a 
  ON z.email1_hist_id=a.email_id 
     or z.email2_hist_id=a.email_id 
 ) b
)c where rnum between 51 and 100;
but I still get the missing right parenthesis error... :(